# Package dependencies cannot be resolved help

Tags: package-management, dependencies, steam

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
steam-launcher: Depends: curl but it is not going to be installed

Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.4 is to be installed
```

How do I get these? because with out them I can't run Steam

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to enable *Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)* in Software Sources, either via Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic depending on which version of Ubuntu you're using.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS